# yield on a function that returns object which includes a promise

Tags: redux-saga

In my saga I have a function I need to yield on but it doesnt return a promise directly. The function is this:

```
export function requestDownload(url): {
    let resolve, reject;
    return {
        type: REQUEST,
        url,
        promise: new Promise(res=>resolve=res, rej=>reject=rej),
        resolve,
        reject
    }
}
```

I need to `yield` on the `promise` field in the return. I tried variations of `call` but am not able to do this. I cannot modify this `requestDownload` function to return the promise directly.

Is this possible with any of the redux-saga helpers?

In summary I am trying to do:

I am trying to do:

```
function* mySaga() {
    yield call(requestDownload, 'blah_url')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
function* mySaga() {
    let action = yield call(requestDownload, 'blah_url')
    try {
        let data = yield action.promise
    } catch(err) {
        // deal with error
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh whoa, you can yield directly on promise's? I gotta try this.

Comment: Is there anyway to write to tell `call` how to extract the promise from the return value? This would be better for me for testability.

Comment: Only thing that comes to my mind is `let {promise} = yield call(requestDownload, 'blah_url')` ... I don't think you will find anything easier than that, but it shouldn't really be an issue while testing.

Comment: Thanks Martin it worked! Isn't it not normal to be able to yield on promises?

Comment: @Noitidart It's part of the redux-saga implementation. It is mentioned here in the notes: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#callfn-args

Comment: Yes yield'ing on `call` `put` etc make sense to me. But why are we able to do `yield action.promise`? The docs say if a promise is the return value its fine, but my promise was not a return value, it was included in the object.

Comment: You are right that this is more general case of yielding a promise, but it is also part of redux-saga implementation. Maybe to get a better understanding you can read a bit about how coroutines work. This article poped up on me as first thing in google http://tobyho.com/2015/12/27/promise-based-coroutines-nodejs/. Redux-saga basically uses coroutines on steroids in that it not only deals with promises but also with effects.

Comment: Thanks very much martin for your help, I'm new to redux-saga and loving it! haha @"co-routines on steroids"